# Low latency serving same data to many clients (multicasting or not...)

Tags: multicast

I need to send identical information to 100's of clients over the Internet. I currently maintain a list of client connections and iterate over the list. Obviously the longer the list gets the more latency there is toward the end of the list.

I have looked at multicasting. However unless I am missing something it is only good for LAN-based communications at present. It requires routers that support multicasting and most routers do not. There is no mechanism that I can see where one requests an available multicast address to avoid broadcasting to an address already in use.

So my questions are:

1) Am I missing something and can I use multicasting to accomplish this? (have tried without success)

2) Other than multicasting, is there a short cut to sending identical packets to many recipients?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by multicasting between threads in the server. Every client connection results in the creation of an object. These objects are stored in a queue. Each object has its own thread and joins the multicast group. When the server multicasts a string to the client objects the delay that arose from the list iteration no longer occurs.

Every now and then there is huge latency (nearly a second). I suspect that this is a JVM thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need high performing low latency IO, you shoud try http://nodejs.org/
You may be also interested in some cache http://memcached.org/